# Remove duplicate rows based on a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this function that check duplicate rows data on a sheet, and remove it. But i need it to check only the first column and use it to remove the entire row. What i have to change?

```
function removerDuplicata() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var intervalo = sheet.getRange("A2:H")
var data = intervalo.getValues();
var novaData = new Array();
for(i in data){
var row = data[i];
var duplicata = false;
for(j in novaData){
  if(row.join() == novaData[j].join()){
    duplicata = true;
  }
}
if(!duplicata){
  novaData.push(row);
}
}
 intervalo.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, novaData.length, 
  novaData[0].length).setValues(novaData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to remove the duplicated rows by checking column "A".

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if(row.join() == novaData[j].join()){
```

#### To:

```
if (row[0] == novaData[j][0]) {
```

#### Note:

- In this case, when `removeDuplicates` is used, the script can be also written as follows.

  ```
    function removerDuplicata() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange("A2:H" + sheet.getLastRow()).removeDuplicates([1]);
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [removeDuplicates(columnsToCompare)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeduplicatescolumnstocompare)

Comment: Hey thanks for that answer.  I didn't know about that new method.  I accomplishes the same thing as the other answer but much fewer lines of code.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you. The method of `removeDuplicates` has been added July 26, 2019. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2019#july_26_2019) It seems that this can simply remove the duplicated rows. But, when the information of duplicated rows is required to be directly retrieved, unfortunately, this is not suitable. And also, in the current stage, the order of removed rows cannot be managed. Please be careful about this.

Comment: I modify to  ```if([row[0]].join() == [novaDados[j][0]].join()){``` and works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Remove Duplicates on Column A

```
function removerDuplicata() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange("A2:H" + sh.getLastRow());
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  var uA = [];
  var o = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!~uA.indexOf(r[0])) {
      uA.push(r[0]);
      o.push(r);
    }
  });
  rg.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(2, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work, the code don't delete the duplicate rows.

Comment: For Each was removed on the new runtime https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#avoid_for_eachvariable_in_object

Comment: for each is different from forEach method of Arrays.  I'm on the new runtime and it works for me.

Comment: hmm ok, i don't know why this isn't working for me :(